# can't connect mongo atlas into mongodb compass, shell and Go app

Tags: mongodb, go, dns, fedora, resolve

i think this question been asked many times, but i've had this issue also last year and another last year, i resolved it to use VPN provider like nordvpn and tunnelBear. my issue here my company has own VPN which to connect to some internal apps, but i cant connect with multi VPN, my company VPN not resolved the issue to connect Mongo Atlas into Compass, after i install NordVPN in my Linux Fedora, it was solve, but i can't open another internal app if i dont connect with my company VPN. so i tried connect my company VPN while my NordVPN connected as well, but it doesnt work. i need to turn off my private VPN to connect my company VPN. this is really confusing for me if keep to turn off and on my private VPN and Company VPN for my work.
wha i have tried to fix this issues but always failed

- change DNS on my fedora `/etc/resolv.conf` into `nameserver 0.0.0.0` or `nameserver 8.8.8.8`;
- change net.bindIp on `/etc/mongod.conf` into `0.0.0.0` and my ip;
- listed ip public in Mongo Atlas `0.0.0.0`;

error on mongo compass after paste the URI:
`querySrv ENODATA _mongodb._tcp.companyNameHere.ycex0.mongodb.net`

error in mongo shell

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
exception: Failed to look up service "_mongodb._tcp.companyNameHere.ycex0.mongodb.net": Success
exiting with code 1
```

error in Go app:

```
panic: error parsing uri: lookup _mongodb._tcp.companyNameHere.ycex0.mongodb.net on XXX.XXX.1.1:53: no such host
```

those ways not work in my Fedora, i cant connect Mongo Atlas URI in Compass, Go App and Shell as well,
is that any another way ?
my os is: Fedora 33

Answer (score 0):

Try using the standard connection string , as SRV strings sometimes not resolvable by some of the images.

The standard connection string can be obtained in the Atlas UI for the version 3.4 earlier

Comment: my company mongo atlas might newer version, is thatstill possible ?

Comment: Yes , it is still possible .

Comment: the uri what i mention above was standart connection what SRE team said, but it doesnt resolve my issue yet till now

Comment: I don't think so this is standard connection string, can you please provide one more time the connection string you are using ?